# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException on a Multi Project Solution (Mixed platforms)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mahapps.metro

I've integrated my WPF project into a mixed solution. This solution has 3 projects written in WinForms (.cs), 1 writtenin WinForms (.vb) and the mine one written in WPF (using MahApps).
The Owner of my project/windows must be the one of the three written in WinForm.

I've made a call like this:

```
using WPFSolution;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;

private void buttonOpenWPFUi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pm = new ProductsMenu();
        ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(pm);
        pm.Show();
    }
```

`ProductsMenu` is my starting point on in the `App.xaml`

But when I reach the `InitializeComponents()` of the `ProductsMenu.xaml.cs` the **System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException** were thrown

The error is: **IOException: Cannot locate resource 'resources/icons.xaml'.**

My App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="WPFSolution.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="ProductsMenu.xaml" ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Red.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <!-- BaseDark.xaml | BaseLight.xaml -->
            <!-- Icons -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFSolution;component/Resources/Icons.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>

            <!-- Languages -->
            <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StringResources.en.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StringResources.it.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,4,7,4"/>
        </Style>


        <!--IMMAGINI -->
        <!--nodi-->
        <!--<BitmapImage x:Key="Nodo1" UriSource="Resources/img/TileImages/nodi/nodo1.jpg"></BitmapImage>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Nodo2" UriSource="Resources/img/TileImages/nodi/nodo2.jpg"></BitmapImage>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Nodo3" UriSource="Resources/img/TileImages/nodi/nodo3.jpg"></BitmapImage>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Nodo4" UriSource="Resources/img/TileImages/nodi/nodo4.jpg"></BitmapImage>-->


    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I've tried to set the Icons.xaml/Build Action as Resource and also as Page.
I'm missing something?

Comment: Is `WPFSolution` the name of the assembly that contains Icons.xaml?

Comment: Yes, it's the assembly that contains the file. If i run the WPF solution as a standalone module, everything works fine.

Comment: And does the application project reference that assembly?

Comment: Yes, I've added the references under: Solution Explorer > MainProject > References > Right Click > Add Reference... > Projects > WPFSolution... Then I checked that the whole solution has the same .NET Framework version (4.6.1)

Answer (score 0):

Got it (or a workaround at least).

1. I've dereferenced the WPFSolution Project.
2. Compiled the WPF solution
       as .dll (I've copied all the merged dictionaries to every
       window.xaml, removed the app.xaml file and change the application
       type to class library)
3. Copied the WPFSolution.dll in the bin/release
       - bin/debug of the main project
4. Referenced the .dll

Everything worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax :

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/WPFSolution;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
```

and also, "Page" is the right build option in this case